# Determine if a physical address is EAST or WEST of a highway (ex. I-95) - Natural Disaster Preparedness

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geolocation

Because of hurricane (and other disasters) evacuation plans, and how they typically work/are planned for, I'm trying to develop a solution involving geolocating address vs. evacuation zones.

Typically, in Georgia for example, employees will be told that everyone that lives EAST of I-95 has to evacuate (based on the guidance from the state). Sometimes it's really bad and everyone East of i-95 as well people West of i-95 have to evacuate. It doesn't matter that magnitude, per se, as if it's west of 95, it's a pretty nasty storm headed right into us and everyone non-essential has to evacuate, so the distance from I-95, for example, doesn't matter, just the direction.

I've looked for answers within the Google Maps docs, Google Search as well as on StackOverflow but I'm not even finding the first breadcrumb that will point me in the correct direction.

Any input and time taken is greatly appreciated. If not, I hope everyone has a great week!

===

I apologize for the confusion. As @Fraser pointed out, every point on Earth is either east/west of I-95 and that is very true and in my haste I didn't consider that. With that being said, it would have to have some sort of boundries, say 100 miles EAST or WEST would be sufficient for this use case.

Comment: Hi @Daneil, do you have a specific question  - it is really not at all clear what it is that you are asking. Are you wanting something like a function that accepts an address and simply says if it is east or west of I-95? As stated it doesn't make sense as every location on the planet is both east and west of I-95 if distance doesn't matter.

Comment: @Fraser - You are absolutely correct, I have added to my post above with further details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pretty easy solution, basically you need to,

1. define the points of I-95,

e.g.

North Miami
Florida, USA
25.886999, -80.215033

Palm Beach County
Florida, USA
26.616067, -80.077996

...

Palmyra
Maine 04965, USA
44.845670, -69.339113

Then you would store those points. in a DB or just in code, e.g. a very rough approx. of the I-95 route is...

```
const I95 = [ 
    [ 25.78364,-80.20397 ],
    [ 25.87672,-80.20764 ],
    [ 25.92758,-80.20947 ],
    [ 25.96093,-80.16689 ],
    [ 26.07565,-80.16895 ],
    [ 26.20202,-80.14286 ],
    [ 26.33871,-80.11540 ],
    [ 26.41732,-80.08916 ],
    [ 26.69125,-80.07053 ],
    [ 26.80963,-80.09800 ],
    [ 26.89172,-80.13457 ],
    [ 27.05956,-80.24473 ],
    [ 27.13447,-80.35813 ],
    [ 27.26235,-80.42439 ],
    [ 27.36947,-80.41054 ],
    [ 27.39591,-80.39414 ],
    [ 27.52203,-80.45045 ],
    [ 27.65044,-80.52553 ],
    [ 27.79038,-80.55236 ],
    [ 28.17599,-80.71639 ],
    [ 29.07689,-81.03222 ],
    [ 29.42123,-81.16468 ],
    [ 30.14514,-81.53397 ],
    [ 30.35867,-81.66032 ],
    [ 30.68282,-81.66581 ],
    [ 30.96873,-81.68229 ],
    [ 31.31721,-81.46740 ],
    [ 31.86616,-81.35713 ],
    [ 32.39924,-81.00667 ],
    [ 32.97139,-80.67807 ],
    [ 33.55893,-80.39473 ],
    [ 34.24241,-79.78304 ],
    [ 34.63655,-79.02817 ],
    [ 35.01769,-78.82628 ],
    [ 35.69044,-78.06967 ],
    [ 36.17135,-77.78567 ],
    [ 36.78059,-77.47569 ],
    [ 37.44699,-77.34057 ],
    [ 38.47267,-77.39426 ],
    [ 39.59907,-75.87815 ],
    [ 40.40772,-74.46824 ],
    [ 41.26384,-73.08396 ],
    [ 41.47261,-71.75990 ],
    [ 42.05443,-71.23805 ],
    [ 42.50737,-71.09643 ],
    [ 43.11185,-70.73388 ],
    [ 44.72099,-69.49369 ],
    [ 44.83018,-68.74662 ],
    [ 46.12428,-68.05448 ]
];
```

2. Geocode your address to get the latitude and longitude.

e.g. Allenhurst. Georgia - `[ 31.786663, -81.609701 ]`

3. For the given geocoded location you would need to determine the closest latitude from your I-95 coordinates that matches. In my example that would be `[ 31.86616,-81.35713 ]`
   Then you just see if the geocoded longitude is greater (East) or less than (West) the I-95 longitude at that latitude.

e.g. as `-81.609701` is less than  `-81.35713`  Allenhurst. Georgia is West of I-95 at around `31.86616` North.

As noted you probably want some "upper bounds" on the test as every point on earth is BOTH East and West of I-95 if one travels far enough. Because if you travel due East or due West from any point you arrive back at that same point :)

You could also do all of this in a spatial DB like PostGIS, MySQL with spatial types, etc - in that case it would be simply a matter of querying the DB to get your "East", "West" result without having to implement your own solution.

Possibly just defining two "areas" or "shapes" that cover the "East" and "West" locations you are interested in. That way it is simply a case of asking "is this [ lat, lng ] 'inside' (in the bounds of) the East or West 'shape'"

Comment: This is very clear and concise and I think this will do the trick. Thank you for taking the time.